# Excel sheet.range().Value holding wrong data

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to take data from an Excel sheet named range and import it to an Access database. However, one range, with text data, is input by a dropdown list. For some reason, it somehow gets turned in data `Variant(1 to 1)`.

Watch window:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| + | `xlx.Range("Talk_codes").Value(7)` |  | `Variant(1 to 1)` | `Form_Logs.GetRangeNames` |

```vb
Select Case xlx.Range("Talk_codes").Value
  Case "Show ID"
    Logs.Show_Promo = Logs.Show_Promo + DateAdd("s", xlx.Range("Talk_Time").Value, Logs.Show_Promo)
```

I know the first cell, at least in the cells, is "Show_ID".
Any suggestions to force it to have the actual data?

Comment: What range does `Talk_codes` refer to?

Comment: `Range.Value()` can take a numeric argument but 7 is not one of the choices...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value

Comment: Talk_codes is a list of values, and the problem exists in all the cells set to text for formats

Comment: 7 is the value watch claims was in the cell, the actual value it should have is "Show ID"  the values watch shows are numbers 1 through to the number of cells

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem when I used the external data wizard.  Perhaps try Starting over with the External Data import wizard.  The wizard is on the ribbon under external data.  navigate to import from excel. Then step through the wizard with next.  make sure to play around with the data types option for talk codes.

Comment: The data in the Talk_codes range is the end-user friendly field names for the type of talk a DJ does, and need to be updated with the values in range Talk_Time which hold the number of seconds to add to the field in the database. The issue is in all the text fields in named ranges.